# To avoid delete for published items

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a requirement to to avoid delete for approved items. Once published the item shouln't be deleted.

I am new to share point. Please help me how can I proceed with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could create an EventReceiver which is colled on ItemDeleting and then cancels the deletingEvent when the item has a Major Version.

However, you should keep a backdoor, in order to delete items. Even if it is not a current Business requirement, you can believe me, the request will come to delete an published item (maybe because it was published by error, ...)

You could also (instead of Publishing) move "approved" items to another document library, where noone has delete-permissions. (or create a workflow doing this when item is approved)

Comment: Is there any other option, other than event receiver like work flow?

Comment: @user2395176 SharePoint 2010 workflow template has the Declare as Record option. Declaring it as record will block deletion.

Answer (score 0):

If in place records management has been [configured](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Configuring-in-place-records-management-7707a878-780c-4be6-9cb0-9718ecde050a), you can declare the item a [record](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Declare-any-list-or-library-item-as-a-record-5d09480c-4b6b-4d3d-b46c-8b90a0f56f59).  The downfall to this is that the item cannot be edited.

Comment: the permission Level will deny deleting of items in any state, but his request is do deny delete only to items in published state.

Comment: You beat me to it. :) Also wanted to add here that you can change the record declaration settings in Site settings -> Record declaration settings to only block delete. Also, in SharePoint 2010, you could declare a record in workflow but it seems they removed that option in 2013. Another way is to create policies but OOB you can only create policies on date fields.

Comment: @LeopoldLerch the 2nd option is correct. If he can somehow automate the record declaration of the item, then deletion will be blocked.

Comment: @LeopoldLerch When I wrote it up, I hadn't included the permissions, then I added them at the end.  Now I remember why I hadn't included them to begin with.